# Lines on degree 2n-3 Fermat hypersufaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, teaching

It is well known that a generic hypersurface of degree $2n-3$ in $\mathbb CP^n$ has finite number of lines. I would like to ask a couple of questions about lines on Fermat hypersurfaces  and their symmetries:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i^{2n-3}=0.$$

Fermat hypersurfaces have a group of automorphisms of order $(2n-3)^n(n+1)!$. In the case $n=3$ (the case of cubic) this group is acting transitively on the collection of $27$ lines and this rases some questions.

The first question is pedagogical, I plan to use it for teaching and really want to know the answer.

*Question 1.* Is there some slick way to give a high-school proof of the fact that there are exactly $27$ lines on Femat cubic in $\mathbb CP^3$ using (or not) the symmetries of the cubic but without using any theory at all?

Further questions are not for teaching, I am just curious about them.

*Question 2.* Is it known that a Fermat hypersurface of degree $2n-3$ has finite number of lines for any 
$n$? Is it known that these lines are never multiple?

*Question 3.* Can one say something about the number of orbits of the action of symmetries on lines on 
a Fermat hypersurface of degree $2n-3$? For example, what happen in the case of quintic, $n=5$? According
to wiki a generic quintic has $2875=125\cdot 23$ lines, so if Fermat quintic is generic, there should be more than one orbit in the action on lines on it. What is the number of orbits?

I would be happy to know the answer on any of these questions.

Comment: The Fermat threefolds contain several one-parameter families of lines: partition the variables into two sets of size 2 and 3 and set them separately to zero.  You obtain $10d$ families of lines in this way.  Of I recall correctly, these are "non-reduced" as soon as $d$ is at least 5.  You can find out more in papers by Albano-Katz and more recently Candelas and others.

Comment: Thank you MP, so together with Sashas answer this solves all my questions apart from the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding question 1, any line in the Fermat cubic $C = \{X_0^3 + X_1^3 + X_2^3 + X_3^3 = 0\}$ must meet the coordinate hyperplane $H_0 = \{X_0 = 0\}$. So which points $x \in (C \cap H_0)$ can lie on lines? If $Y, Z$ are homogenous coordinates on $T_x(C \cap H_0) \cong \mathbb{P}^1$, then the restriction of $X_0^3 + X_1^3 + X_2^3 + X_3^3$ to $T_x C$ is of the form $X_0^3 + F(Y,Z)$ for a homogeneous cubic $F$. For $x$ to lie on a line, $X_0^3 + F$ must factorise, so $F$ is a cube. This means that $x$ is an inflection point of the plane cubic curve $C \cap H_0 = \{X_1^3 + X_2^3 + X_3^3 = 0\}$. The inflection points are given by intersection with the zero set of the Hessian determinant $216X_1X_2X_3$. Hence the intersection of any line in $C$ with any coordinate hyperplane must actually have two corrdinates equal to 0, and it follows that the lines consist of $\{X_0^3 + X_1^3 = X_2^3 + X_3^3 = 0\}$ and its two images under permutating the coordinates (9 lines in each).

P.S. Here is a related exercise I like. Once one has identified the 27 lines in the Fermat cubic $C$, one can use the symmetries of $C$ to guess how to arrange 6 points in $\mathbb{P}^2$ so that the blow-up is isomorphic to $C$, and then write down an explicit rational map $\mathbb{P}^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$ that maps birationally onto $C$.

Comment: In fact I have a couple of questions. Do I understand correctly that by $T_xC\cap H_0$ you mean the tangent projective line to $C\cap H_0$?  
Why $X_0^3+F$ must factorisу for $x$ to lie on a line?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you want to write the restiction as $X_0^3+F(Y,Z)$. Any function on a line can be written as $F(Y,Z)$?
(maybe I don't understand what you mean when you say that $Y,Z$ are homogeneous coordinates on the line). 

But anyway thank you for giving this proof, I got the main idea and the style of the proof is almost as elementary as I would like it to be. 

Comment: In the same order as your questions: Yes, I do. If `$x$` lies on a line, then that line is contained in `$T_xC$`, and its defining equation is a factor in `$X_0^3 + F$`. `$F(Y,Z)$` is indeed intended to mean an arbitrary cubic on the line `$T_x(C \cap H_0)$`; what I try to emphasise (perhaps unsuccessfully) is that the restriction of equation of `$C$` to `$T_xC \cong \mathbb{P}^2$`, which is a cubic in `$X_0$`, `$Y$` and `$Z$`, does not contain any cross-terms like `$X_0Y^2$`.

Comment: Johannes, thanks again for the proof. Also, by any chance, do you know a book that contains this exercise with cubic surface?  

Comment: I don't have any references for the specifics of my answer, but I've found the first of Reid's Chapters on Algebraic Surfaces (arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9602006) a useful general reference for cubic surfaces.

Comment: Thank you for telling about Reid's chapters. I guess I should look into this text again

Answer (score 4):

Assume for example that $n = 2k + 1$ is odd. Let $\xi^{2n-3} = -1$. Then for any $(y_0,y_1,\dots,y_k) \in \mathbb{CP}^k$ the point $(y_0,\xi y_0,y_1,\xi y_1,\dots,y_k, \xi y_k)$ is on the Fermat hypersurface. So, it contains $\mathbb{CP}^k$. In particular, if $k \ge 2$ (and so $n \ge 5$) the number of lines is infinite. A similar argument works for even $n \ge 6$.

Comment: Thanks Sasha, this is neat! I still wonder about the cubic and the quintic. 